# Second derivatives of Healpy map

Tags: healpy

Is there a way  in Healpy to get the second derivatives in theta and phi of a Healpy map?
(ideally both the mixed derivative theta phi  and   the derivatives theta theta, phi phi)

Something like the optional output `der2` of the `alm2map_der` function for the Fortran version of Healpix.